Error in executing model training with stable diffusion
this is my first time using SD to train a model. I executed the text_to_image. py file, but encountered an error. The command I executed is as follows:
accelerate launch --mixed_precision="fp16"  train_text_to_image_lora.py \
  --pretrained_model_name_or_path=stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0 \
  --dataset_name=hwjyz \
  --dataloader_num_workers=8 \
  --resolution=512 \
  --center_crop \
  --random_flip \
  --train_batch_size=1 \
  --gradient_accumulation_steps=4 \
  --max_train_steps=15000 \
  --learning_rate=1e-04 \
  --max_grad_norm=1 \
  --lr_scheduler="cosine" \
  --lr_warmup_steps=0 \
  --output_dir=hwjyz_out \
  --report_to=wandb \
  --checkpointing_steps=500 \
  --seed=1337

The error screenshot returned is as follows：
enter image description here
I opened the file and the specific error line number is as follows. It seems that there was an error loading the VAE model. May I ask if anyone can help me? Thank you very much
enter image description here
Please tell me exactly what to do, where the problem is, and how to make specific modifications. Thank you
